# Swift 2.0 for IOS

Tags: swift2, xcode7

I have a pc running windows 7 , and when i heard that apple is making swift open source , I started studying about it, but don't know how to start testing apps , is there anything else than xcode to develop apps for ios using swift , I thought it should be available since it became open source.
Xcode is only available for mac users :(
Any thoughts?

Comment: Swift is open source. iOS tools are not open source.

Comment: So they made swift available but no IDE to build apps with it :o?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is only compatible with `macOS`.

The framework to built apps for iOS with `Swift` is only for `macOS`.
You can use `Swift` language with windows using [Swift for Windows](https://swiftforwindows.codeplex.com/)

Otherwise you must have to have an apple computer